# Bootstrap Navbar Problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I'm coming back to Django after a year in Flask. Since then I have grown comfortable using Bootstrap 3, and I'd like to bring it over to Django. Unfortunately, I'm running into some serious problems from the get-go. Specifically, I am having a hell of a time getting the navbar to work.

In Firefox, I have managed to get the navbar looking nice and getting the dropdowns to work. The only problem, which is hard to see in the picture bellow, is that text goes *under* the bar. Some css wizardry should fix this, but my primary motivation for using Bootstrap is to *not* muck about with CSS as much.

[image: A well behaved toolbar...mostly...]

In Chrome on the other hand, everything is wrong. Very wrong. There is something going on that *does not involve the toolbar at all...*

[image: Wrong. Wrong. Also, Wrong.]

I've looked around for this type of problem on the ol' SE, googled around, referenced Bootstrap's wall of browser shaming, but I can't find anything, and I don't know enough about CSS and browsers to recognize anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04 (haven't checked it elsewhere yet).

Bellow is the code for the files, with home extending base, and including the code in nav.

**home.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
OASIS - Home
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>NONE</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**base.html:**

```
{% load compress %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}favicon.ico">

    {% compress css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}stylesheets/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    {% endcompress %}

    {% compress js %}
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL}}javascripts/libs/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL}}javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="{{ STATIC_URL}}javascripts/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>-->
    {% endcompress %}

</head>
<body>
    {% include "nav.html" %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}

    {% compress js %}
    {% endcompress %}

    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-6516194-8'],['_trackPageview']]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**nav.html:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-header" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="logo" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/oasis_logo_tiny.png"></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OASIS ON</a>  
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Admin<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Library<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Collected Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Member Works</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">OASIS Canon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>
OASIS - Home
</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
    
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <!--<script src="/static/javascripts/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>-->
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-header" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="logo" src="/static/img/oasis_logo_tiny.png"></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OASIS ON</a>  
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Admin<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Library<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Collected Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Member Works</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">OASIS Canon</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

    
<h1>NONE</h1>

    
    
    
    
    <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-6516194-8'],['_trackPageview']]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.: I'm not seeing any errors pop up on either browser's developer tools, although there is a decent chance that I am not using them correctly. Is there something I can do to better debug these things?

Comment: consider providing a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with Python or Django. Please change the title and remove the tags.

Comment: Not directly, no. I changed the tags and title to reflect this.

Comment: @rll I added a jsfiddle. The problem seems to be in the files I'm linking to. Instead of using static files on my hard drive, I used the links provided currently on the bootstrap "getting started" page ("http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/"). This fixes the major problem in the chrome browser, but it still leaves the text sliding under the navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `navbar-fixed-top`. If you read the Bootstrap documentation, it specifically states:

> Body padding required
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the `<body>` Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the `navbar` is 50px high.

So, to solve this issue, adding this to your `css`:

```
body { 
  padding-top: 70px; 
}
```

Note: Bootstrap recommends 70px, but I usually stick with the 15px margin, so 65px is a good number.

```css
body{
  padding-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <title>
    OASIS - Home
    </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">


        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
        
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
        
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
            <!--<script src="/static/javascripts/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>-->
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-header" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img alt="logo" src="/static/img/oasis_logo_tiny.png"></a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OASIS ON</a>  
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Admin<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Library<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Collected Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Member Works</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">OASIS Canon</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

        
    <h1>NONE</h1>

        
        
        
        
        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-6516194-8'],['_trackPageview']]; // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For more information, see [The Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I introduced that when I was throwing the kitchen sink at the last problem (was just "navbar navbar-inverse"). Returning that fixed the problem. I think just making the JSFiddle really helped. Could you recommend anything else (without going into another post) for troubleshooting these types of issues?

Comment: Technically that isn't a JSFiddle, it's just a code snippet, but works the same way. Honestly, just keep using the framework, you'll learn all it's oddities and nuances in no time. This issue on the other hand could have been avoided by reading the documentation, so don't forget to do that. Cheers.